# Rails 4 Carrierwave duplicate entries when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, duplicates, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave gem to add an attachment module into my application. To do so, I created a model concern named `Attachable` as follow :

```
module Attachable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
  end
end
```

which I'm calling into my post model :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Attachable
end
```

When it works fine for saving a new posts :

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new( post_params )
  if @post.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post.slug)
  else
    @categories = Term.get_category
    render :new
  end
end
```

it actually duplicate my entries (database) when I'm updating :

```
def update
  @post.clean_taxonomies
  if @post.update( post_params )
    redirect_to post_path(@post.slug)
  else
    @categories = Term.get_category
    render :edit
  end
end
```

When editing, it repopulate all the attachments title (field name:string in my table) but since it can't repopulate the filename into the `input field`, when I save the modifications, it duplicate the number of attachments with an empty file.

How can I fix that and upload/save an attachment only if it has been defined?

Thanks

**EDIT :**
Here is my view source on `posts/edit.html.haml` (the same as new.html.haml) :

```
= form_for @product, url: product_path(@product.slug), html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = f.fields_for :attachments do |attachment|
    .row.attachment
      .col-sm-6
        = attachment.label :name, 'Filename'
        = attachment.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
      .col-sm-5.col-xs-9
        = attachment.label :file, 'File'
        = attachment.file_field :file, class: 'form-control'
      .col-sm-1.col-xs-1
        %a.remove-attachment{ href: '#' }
          %i.icon-remove-circle.icon-2x
```

Comment: Would you post your view? The problem is very likely there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edited my post and added the view code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution. I needed to use `reject_if` on my `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as :

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments,
                              allow_destroy: true,
                              reject_if: lambda { |a| a['file'].blank? }
```

It works like a charm :)